# Java operator to check if either conditions are false, but not both or none

Tags: java, logic

Is there an operator in Java that will give a result of false if either conditions are false, but if both are true or both false the result will be true?

I have some code that relies on a user entering some values for a process to run. As the user should only be able to enter x or y but not both or none I would like to show an error message in this case.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You want XNOR, basically:

```
if (!(a ^ b))
```

or (more simply)

```
if (a == b)
```

where `a` and `b` are the conditions.

Sample code:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        xnor(false, false);
        xnor(false, true);
        xnor(true, false);
        xnor(true, true);
    }

    private static void xnor(boolean a, boolean b)
    {
        System.out.printf("xnor(%b, %b) = %b\n", a, b, a == b);
    }
}
```

Produces this truth table;

```
xnor(false, false) = true
xnor(false, true) = false
xnor(true, false) = false
xnor(true, true) = true
```

Comment: Jon, it would probably be beneficial to show the full logic table for the XOR operator in this case. I would do it here, but the comment formatting is horrible for this.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for! I knew there was an operator, just couldn't remember it :)

Comment: @James: I've edited this with a simpler way of doing this - the equality operator!

Comment: Also, yes, `!=` is simpler. But !XOR is the correct boolean operator for this case. So I still like your answer the best.

Comment: That definition of xnor as !(A ^ B) looks a bit unusual, (A ^ B) v (!A ^ !B)

Comment: @jdmichal: != is actually wrong; that gives XOR instead of XNOR. @Andrew: I think of XNOR as the inverse of XOR, leading to that representation. It has the advantage of only evaluating each condition once...

Comment: @Jon, running True,True through your expression though gives !(true and true) = false, unless you mean't something else in the ascii representation.

Comment: @Andrew: I don't see what you mean. true ^ true is false, so !(true ^ true) is true. I never wrote "and". Could you clarify?

Comment: Your ascii representation ^ is meaning something other than 'and', which would be the common interpretation of that symbol. Consequence of ascii vs logic symbols.

Comment: This question was given in the context of Java. In Java, the `^` symbol represents the bit-operation XOR.

Comment: @Andrew: It's not an *ASCII* representation - it's code. It's an "if" condition, in the context of a Java question. I haven't used the symbol ^ anywhere other than in a code font, for a real snippet of code, in a question about coding.

Comment: My mistake, I was reading it as a logical statement independant of a language. When I wrote the original comment, I put in XNor as it would be expressed in a mathematical statement.